# adding company model to account class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently trying to add an extra model within the account model class like so

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public int companyID { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyDetails company { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int companyID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

What I am not sure about is how do I create a DBSet with company class and would the ID column of company show up in the users table?

Comment: You have a type named as a View Model, but want a `DbSet<T>`: I think you might be mixing up Model and View Model. Are you looking for this in EF or on the client?

Comment: @Richard I am looking for this on EF.  The RegisterViewModel was auto generated when I created the project.

Comment: On second thoughts I don't think it's EF.  What I am trying to achieve is basically to have a foreign key within the user table which will link up with the company table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 5 utilizes Identity, which among other things comes default with an `ApplicationUser` class. This is your application's "user" and what is persisted by Entity Framework to your database. As a result, you need to add additional relationships here, not `RegisterViewModel`, which as it's name indicates, is a view model, not an entity.

**IdentityModels.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual CompanyDetails Company { get; set; }
}
```

Once you generate a migration and update your database, your `dbo.CompanyDetails` table will be created and a foreign key to that table will be added to `dbo.AspNetUsers` (the table for `ApplicationUser`)

You'll of course need to keep the property on `RegisterViewModel` in order to actually edit those fields with that view model, but you can remove the `virtual` keyword. The `virtual` keyword means that the property or method can be overridden, which is necessary in the case of a navigation property on an entity so that Entity Framework can attach the lazy-loading logic on the proxy classes it creates. That's probably more info than you need, but long and short, it's not needed on your view model.

Comment: I did some more digging around and realised that my companydetails entity should be put in IdentityModels,cs.  Should I also move the company details class into the IdentityModels.cs file?  I also found IdentityDBContext not sure if I should be using that too, to achieve what I want

Comment: No. Honestly, I'm not sure why the MVC devs chose to setup the project template that way. Traditionally, each class gets its own file. So `CompanyDetails` would go in `CompanyDetails.cs`. You don't *have* to do it this way, obviously, but it makes maintaining your app much easier, as you don't have to think about what file a class is in.